# How would you translate: 毎日は楽しくなりました。

Tags: grammar, translation

毎日は楽しくなりました。

Would you translate this: Every day was fun.

or

Every day became fun.

I know that なる can be used to say that A becomes B.  But in this example what is the nuance of the meaning of なる？

Comment: Can you make the question more specific?  This site is not for translation but for finer points in the Japanese languages.  If you just want a translation, please use translation services.  See also [meta discussion](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76/should-pure-translation-questions-be-allowed).

Comment: (Please read “Japanese languages” as “the Japanese language” in my previous comment.  I wrote it incorrectly while editing the comment before posting.)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: you can edit comments too.

Comment: @crunchyt: A user can edit a comment only in the first five minutes after he/she posts it (unless the user is a moderator).  It was too late when I realized the mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  But I find this Japanese sentence unnatural (mostly because of the part 毎日は).  Can you add a context where it is used?  I know that the 毎日は part is not the main concern of the question, but the context may be useful to answer your question, too.

Comment: @Paul, I think Tsuyoshi means the は, I haven't often seen a は after 毎日. Maybe a が would be more natural? By the way, I've stood in that same spot as you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

毎日は楽しくなりました generally makes it seem like the context is:

1) everyday life was not much fun before

2) a particular thing happened and pretty much changed it over night

3) everyday life is now fun.

Thus, it's difficult to actually translate this into an English sentence that contains all that context. Something like "everyday life became fun".

As for Kdansky's post above, the てしまった form *could* add more emphasis on the fact that "yeah, it really DID become fun". However, the てきた form that he used implies something slightly different: that it wasn't a "particular thing" that changed the situation "overnight", but rather that everyday life steadily became more enjoyable, and now it is fun.